# belongsToManyRelation not working in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-relations

I have many to many relation which is inserting data correctly but when I try to fetch data it gives me no data.

one table is **boss** and other is **workers**

`Migration`

```
<?php



public function up()
{
Schema::create('boss_worker', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->id();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('worker_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('boss_id');
$table->timestamps();
});
}
```

Boss model relation

```
  public function workers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Admin\Worker::class,'boss_worker');
    }
```

How I am trying to fetch data

```
public function index()
{

$boss = Boss::find(1);
dd($boss->workers);

}
```

How I am inserting data

```
$input = $request->all();
$workers = $input['workers'];
$input['workers'] = implode(',', $workers);

$boss = Boss::where('staff_id',$request->boss)->first();

$worker_gangs = $boss->workers()->sync($workers);
```

It is not fetching any data

Comment: Can you show a dump of our `$input['workers']` when you insert the data?

Answer (score 0):

**use**

```
public function index()
{

$boss = Boss::with('workers')->find(1);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a relationship from a model you are calling to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` so, you can access and apply any filter or query with the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries), to fetch the data from that relationship, you have to use these methods to execute the query

```php
->get();
->first();
```

your code have to be:

```php
$boss = Boss::find(1);
$workers = $boss->workers()->get();
dd($workers);
```

or you can make [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) with the Boss model

```php
$boss = Boss::with('workers')->find(1);
dd($boss->workers);
```